# POSTGRESQL unable to compare null columns

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Following is my SQL query:

```
update table 
set unit_id = T1.unit_id_temp from
       (select case when unit_id4 is not null then unit_id4
        when unit_id3 is not null then unit_id3
        when unit_id2 is not null then unit_id2
        when unit_id1 is not null then unit_id1
        else unit_id
        end as unit_id_temp,
        unit_id1,unit_id2,unit_id3,unit_id4
        from   table)  T1
where table.unit_id4  = T1.unit_id4
and   table.unit_id3  = T1.unit_id3
and   table.unit_id2  = T1.unit_id2  
and   table.unit_id1  = T1.unit_id1
```

From the above query i am unable to compare columns when they are NULL, as the condition returns false.

For Example:
when unit_id4 is null ,
     table.unit_id4 = T1.unit_id4 returns False.

Hence my update fails whenever either of the columns contain NULL vallues.

I tried using is not distinct from, it does not work. Throws the following error:

UPDATE - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "distinct"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can replace your entire query with this:

```
UPDATE table
SET unit_id = COALESCE(unit_id4, unit_id3, unit_id2, unit_id1)
WHERE COALESCE(unit_id4, unit_id3, unit_id2, unit_id1) IS NOT NULL
```

It seems to me that your logic is to update the `unit_id` column to `unit_id4`, `unit_id3`, `unit_id2`, `unit_id1`, if any of these columns be not `NULL`, in this order.  The `COALESCE` function works well for this use case.  In the event that *all* four columns are `NULL`, the logic in your `UPDATE` is to simply assign the same value back to `unit_id`.  The `WHERE` clause in my query will prevent the `UPDATE` from even running on records where all four unit columns be `NULL`, so there will never be any wasted effort.

Comment: Okay., I am so sorry I missed some information: I am trying this on AWS Redshift.  I tried the previous query already and what I got was ": Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate"

Comment: I would drop your original query if I were you, because I think it can be rewritten more simply.

Comment: urghhhh., thanks a lot.. that makes me dumb.. It dint snap my mind to use COALESCE.